# Applying multiple tuples to the same function (i.e. `apply(f, tuples...)`) without recursion or `tuple_cat`

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, c++17

[`std::experimental::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply) has the following signature:

```
template <class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t);
```

It basically invokes `f` by expanding `t`'s elements as the arguments.

---

I would like something that does the exact same thing, but with multiple tuples at the same time:

```
template <class F, class... Tuples>
constexpr decltype(auto) multi_apply(F&& f, Tuples&&... ts);
```

Example usage:

```
std::tuple t0{1, 2, 3};
std::tuple t1{4, 5, 6};
auto sum = [](auto... xs){ return (0 + ... + xs); };

assert(multi_apply(sum, t0, t1) == 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6);
```

---

I can think of various naive way of implementing `multi_apply`:

- Use [`std::tuple_cat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) and then calling `std::experimental::apply`.
- Use recursion to bind every tuple's arguments to a series of lambdas that eventually call the original function.

But what I'm asking is: **how can I implement `multi_apply` without resorting to `std::tuple_cat` or recursion?**

What I ideally would like to do is: generate an [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for every tuple and match every tuple with its own index sequence **in the same variadic expansion**. Is this possible? Example:

```
// pseudocode-ish
template <class F, std::size_t... Idxs, class... Tuples>
constexpr decltype(auto) multi_apply_helper(
    F&& f, std::index_sequence<Idxs>... seqs,  Tuples&&... ts)
{
    return f(std::get<Idxs>(ts)...);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with `std::tuple_cat`?

Comment: You could build your own versions of tuple_size and get that work recursively, then the implementation of multi_apply is essentially the same as apply.

Comment: are you trying to optimize compile duration? are your tuples of varying sizes?

Comment: If this is about what I think it's about, `tuple_cat` is just fine as long as you use it on tuples of references.

Comment: This question isn't very useful unless we know what you think is wrong with tuple_cat, as a valid answer could just literally reimplememt tuple_cat with a different name.  Also you've put multiple questions into a single question, which is frowned upon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my take on it. It doesn't use recursion and it expands those tuples in the same pack expansion, but it requires a bit of preparation:

- We build a tuple of references to the tuples passed in, rvalue references for rvalue arguments, lvalue references for lvalue arguments, in order to have proper forwarding in the final call (exactly what `std::forward_as_tuple` does, as T.C. noted in the comments). The tuple is built and passed around as an rvalue, so reference collapsing ensures correct value categories for each argument in the final call to `f`.
- We build two flattened index sequences, both of size equal to the sum of all tuple sizes:

  - The outer indices select the tuple, so they repeat the same value (the tuple's index in the tuple pack) a number of times equal to the size of each tuple.
  - The inner ones select the element in each tuple, so they increase from `0` to one less than the tuple size for each tuple.

Once we have that in place, we just expand both index sequences in the call to `f`.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t S, class... Ts> constexpr auto make_indices()
{
   constexpr std::size_t sizes[] = {std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>>...};
   using arr_t = std::array<std::size_t, S>;
   std::pair<arr_t, arr_t> ret{};
   for(std::size_t c = 0, i = 0; i < sizeof...(Ts); ++i)
      for(std::size_t j = 0; j < sizes[i]; ++j, ++c)
      {
         ret.first[c] = i;
         ret.second[c] = j;
      }
   return ret;
}

template<class F, class... Tuples, std::size_t... OuterIs, std::size_t... InnerIs> 
constexpr decltype(auto) multi_apply_imp_2(std::index_sequence<OuterIs...>, std::index_sequence<InnerIs...>, 
                                           F&& f, std::tuple<Tuples...>&& t)
{
   return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<InnerIs>(std::get<OuterIs>(std::move(t)))...);
}

template<class F, class... Tuples, std::size_t... Is> 
constexpr decltype(auto) multi_apply_imp_1(std::index_sequence<Is...>, 
                                           F&& f, std::tuple<Tuples...>&& t)
{
   constexpr auto indices = make_indices<sizeof...(Is), Tuples...>();
   return multi_apply_imp_2(std::index_sequence<indices.first[Is]...>{}, std::index_sequence<indices.second[Is]...>{},
      std::forward<F>(f), std::move(t));
}

template<class F, class... Tuples> 
constexpr decltype(auto) multi_apply(F&& f, Tuples&&... ts)
{
   constexpr std::size_t flat_s = (0U + ... + std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuples>>);
   if constexpr(flat_s != 0)
      return multi_apply_imp_1(std::make_index_sequence<flat_s>{}, 
         std::forward<F>(f), std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Tuples>(ts)...));
   else
      return std::forward<F>(f)();
}

int main()
{
   auto t0 = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
   auto t1 = std::make_tuple(3, 6, 4, 5);
   auto sum = [](auto... xs) { return (0 + ... + xs); };

   std::cout << multi_apply(sum, t0, t1, std::make_tuple(7)) << '\n';
}
```

It compiles on the trunk versions of Clang and GCC in C++1z mode. In terms of generated code, GCC with `-O2` optimizes the call to `multi_apply` to a constant `28`.

---

Replacing `std::array` with a built-in array inside `make_indices` by `using arr_t = std::size_t[S];` makes it compile on Clang 3.9.1 (that version of libc++ lacks `constexpr` on `std::array`'s `operator[]`).

Further replacing `std::tuple_size_v` with `std::tuple_size<X>::value` and removing the `if constexpr` test in `multi_apply` makes it compile on GCC 6.3.0. (The test handles the cases when no tuples are passed in or all tuples passed in are empty.)

Further replacing the uses of fold expressions with calls like

```
sum_array({std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuples>>...})
```

where `sum_array` can be something simple like

```
template<class T, std::size_t S> constexpr T sum_array(const T (& a)[S], std::size_t i = 0)
{
   return i < S ? a[i] + sum_array(a, i + 1) : 0;
}
```

makes it compile on the latest MSVC 2017 RC (MSVC actually has `std::tuple_size_v`, but it needs the other changes). The generated code is still great: after replacing the body of the `sum` lambda with `sum_array({xs...})`, the resulting code is a direct call to `sum_array` with the array built in-place directly from the elements of all tuples, so the `multi_apply` machinery doesn't introduce any run time overhead.

---

`std::apply` is defined in terms of *INVOKE*, so, to keep things consistent, the final call to `f` should be

```
std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::get<InnerIs>(std::get<OuterIs>(std::move(t)))...)
```

Implementations may provide a noexcept-specifier on `std::apply` (at least, libc++ does; libstdc++ and MSVC currently don't) so that may be worth considering too.

Comment: `std::tuple<Tuples&&...>{std::forward<Tuples>(ts)...}` this is just `forward_as_tuple`, no?

Comment: @T.C. Absolutely right. Just look at my spankin' new reinvented wheel... it's just like the other one, but it's *mine*.

Comment: Great answer. Exactly what I hoped to see! :)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Cheers! I've added some implementation notes at the end.

Comment: @bogdan: unfortunately [clang++3.9.1 does not seem to like the `make_indices`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dWWS2lTH8CcVCznY) function. It does work with clang SVN though.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo It's due to that version of libc++ lacking `constexpr` on `std::array`'s `operator[]`. You can replace `std::array` with a built-in array inside `make_indices` by `using arr_t = std::size_t[S];`. Actually, I think I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Done, with additional solutions for GCC 6.3.0 and MSVC 2017 RC.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative version:

```
template <class F, std::size_t... Is, class ... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) multiple_apply_impl(F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&... ts)
{
    constexpr auto p = [](){
        constexpr auto total_size = sizeof...(Is);
        std::array<std::size_t, total_size> outer{};
        std::array<std::size_t, total_size> inner{};
        std::size_t global_index = 0;
        std::size_t outer_value = 0;

        [[maybe_unused]] auto l = [&](std::size_t size)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
                outer[global_index] = outer_value;
                inner[global_index] = i;
                ++global_index;
            }
            ++outer_value;
        };
        (l(std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Ts>>::value), ...);

        return make_pair(outer, inner);
    }();
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto outer = p.first;
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto inner = p.second;

    using std::get;
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f),
                       get<inner[Is]>(get<outer[Is]>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)))...);
}

template <class F, class ... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) multiple_apply(F&& f, Ts&&... ts)
{
    constexpr auto total_size = (std::size_t{0} + ... + std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Ts>>::value);

    return multiple_apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f),
                               std::make_index_sequence<total_size>(),
                               std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/yIuWVQ)